# How to use double groupby in Pandas and filter based on if condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame called df that looks like this in Pandas:

```
**id        amt          date       seq**
SB      450,000,000  2020-05-11  1
OM      430,000,000  2020-05-11  1
SB      450,000,000  2020-05-12  1
OM      450,000,000  2020-05-12  1
OM      130,000,000  2020-05-12  2
```

I need to find the value in amt for each ID for each day. The issue is that one some days there are multiple cycles as indicated by "seq".

If there are 2 cycles (aka seq=2) for any one day, I need to take the value when seq=2 for that id on that day, and drop any values for seq=1 with the same day and id. Some days there are only 1 cycle for any one id, and on those days I can just stick with the value where seq=1.

My goal is to Pandas groupby day and then again groupby id, then apply an if statement for if the seq column contains a 2 for that id and that day, then filter that groupby object to only include the row where seq=2 for that day and id. The end result would be a data frame with only the rows where seq=2 for any day when there are multiple cycles and `seq=1` or `2`, and the rows where seq=1 for days where there is only one cycle and seq=1 for all ids.

So far I have tried:

```
`for day in df.groupby(df['date']):
    for id in day[1].groupby(['id']):
        if 2 in id[1]['seq']:
            id[1]=id[1].apply(lambda g: g[g['seq']==2])`
```

Which gives me:
KeyError: 'seq'

and I have also tried:

```
`for day in df.groupby(df['date']):
    for id in day[1].groupby(['id']):
        id=list(id)
        if 2 in id[1]['seq']:
            id[1]=id[1][id[1]['seq']==2]`
```

Which runs fine but then doesn't actually change or doing anything to df (same number of rows remain).

Can anyone help me with how I can accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you groupby date + id, then get the indices of the rows where seq is at it's maximum for those groupings. Once you get the those indices, you can slice back into the original dataframe to get your desired subset:

```
max_seq_indices = df.groupby(["date", "**id"])["seq**"].idxmax()

print(max_seq_indices)
date        **id
2020-05-11  OM      1
            SB      0
2020-05-12  OM      4
            SB      2
Name: seq**, dtype: int64
```

Looking at the values of this Series, you can see that we have a maximum seq for ["2020-05-11", "OM"] at row 1. Likewise, there is a maximum seq for ["2020-05-11", "SB"] at row 0. And so on. If we use this to slice back into our original dataframe, we end up with a subset that you described in your question:

```
new_df = df.loc[max_seq_indices]

print(new_df)
  **id          amt        date  seq**
1   OM  430,000,000  2020-05-11      1
0   SB  450,000,000  2020-05-11      1
4   OM  130,000,000  2020-05-12      2
2   SB  450,000,000  2020-05-12      1
```

This approach will encounter issues if your have a seq greater than 2, but only want the rows where seq is 2. However if that is the case, leave a comment and I can update my answer with a more robust (but probably more complex) solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with a sorted dataframe like:

```
df.sort_values(['date', '**id', 'seq**'], inplace=True)
```

Then you can use groupby to take just the last of each group

```
df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby(['date', '**id'])['amt'].agg('last')
```